# Binary Operator for Template Class Doesn't Resolve Implicit Conversion

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following classes, where the first is templated. Both are meant to hold a numeric value.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(T val) : val{ val } {}
    T val;
};

struct bar
{
    bar(double val) : val{ val } {}
    double val;
};
```

I want to define a way to add these classes together to get a new one with a different value.

```cpp
template<typename T>
foo<T> operator+(foo<T> a, foo<T> b)
{
    return foo<T>(a.val + b.val);
}

bar operator+(bar a, bar b)
{
    return bar(a.val + b.val);
}
```

When I use these operators with implicit conversion, the operator using object of type `foo` doesn't use the implicit conversion on the double value to apply my overloaded operator, even though it can do it for the non-template class. The result is that there is no operator matching the types in that expression.

```cpp
int main()
{
    foo<double> foo_value(11.0);
    bar bar_value(11.0);

    foo<double> ev1 = foo_value + 1.0; // no operator matches these operands
    bar ev2 = bar_value + 1.0;
}
```

Does the operator have to be explicitly instantiated first? If so, a) how does that look like, and b) why isn't the instantiation done implicitly, if it can be done when initializing an object of type `foo<double>`?

If the standard doesn't support any sort of resolution without explicitly casting `1.0` to a value of type `foo<double>`, I presume the only other possibility is defining operator overloads for each type I want to use like that (for both lhs and rhs)?

Comment: `bar_value` and `1.0` are different types and will not match a single `T` and `1.0` No implicit conversions prevents a lot of grief in template programming.

Comment: There's no problem with the statement `bar ev2 = bar_value + 1.0`; implicit conversion is used to match my defined operator. That's not the case with `foo<double> ev2 = foo_value + 1.0` even though the implicit conversion seems obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you have to remember about templates is that they will **not** do a conversion for you.  All they do is try and figure out the types things are, and if that jives with template parameters, then it will stamp out the function and call it.

In you case when you do

```
foo_value + 1.0
```

the compiler goes okay, lets see if we have any `operator +` that will work for this.  It finds

```
template<typename T>
foo<T> operator+(foo<T> a, foo<T> b)
{
    return foo<T>(a.val + b.val);
}
```

and then it tries to figure out what `T` is so it can stamp out a concrete function.  It looks at `foo_value`, sees it is a `foo<double>` so it says for the first parameter `T` needs to be a `double`.  Then it looks at `1.0` and goes okay, I have a `double` and that is when you run into a problem.  The compiler can't deduce what `T` should be for `b` because it expects a `foo<some_type>`, but got a `double` instead.  Because it can't deduce a type, your code fails to compile.

In order to get the behavior you want you would need to add

```
template<typename T>
foo<T> operator+(foo<T> a, T b)
{
    return foo<T>(a.val + b);
}
```

Which lets you add a `T` to a `foo<T>`, or better yet

```
template<typename T, typename U>
foo<T> operator+(foo<T> a, U b)
{
    return foo<T>(a.val + b);
}
```

Which lets you add anything to a `foo<T>` (`foo<double> + int` for instance where the first version would not allow that)

Comment: I tried the latter, and if you define the template like that for both lhs and rhs, the compiler won't know which operator it should use, and it will be an ambiguous call.

Comment: @Riddick I'd have to see that code to tell you why it didn't work.  It works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d53b1a298c0642);

Comment: I figured out what happened when I got an ambiguous call: I am asking for the parameter as the parent class type (not shown in the question). So I'm assuming since it doesn't fit the arguments precisely, adding the two additional overloads introduces ambiguity when I pass child classes. When I cast to parent, it works.

Comment: @Riddick Sounds plausible.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is there any practical reason it doesn't attempt to apply implicit conversions in the template case? The way I reason, if it can match object `bar` to a double _and_ I can create a variable with `foo foo_value(1.0)` (and have it correctly match the template), it seems within reach to implicitly convert the argument to the right type too. Would that make function matching too greedy?

Comment: @Riddick The practical reason is there could be any any number of things it could do a conversion to.  Lets say you have two types (`A` and `B`) that can convert to each other, and you pass them to a function template that only takes a single type.  Does the compile convert `A` to a `B`, or does it convert `B` to an `A`?  Trying to solve that problem, and all of the other edge cases, would make the rules for templates and order of magnitude more complex then they are already, and they are pretty complex as is.

Comment: Could I ask you in chat about the larger problem I'm trying to resolve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193795/discussion-between-nathanoliver-and-riddick).